# Switching between dark/light style overrides

Tags: material-ui

I want to override the color of some icons based on `theme.type` to a native `PaletteColor`. I can check the `type` and conditionally set the color like this:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    someIcon: {
      color:
        theme.palette.type === "dark"
          ? theme.palette.warning.dark
          : theme.palette.warning.light,
    },
  })
);
```

This is pretty verbose every time I want to override something though, so it can be refactored to `themeColor` below:

```js
const themeColor = (theme: Theme, color: PaletteColor) =>
  theme.palette.type === "dark"
    ? color.dark
    : color.light;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    someIcon: {
      color: themeColor(theme, theme.palette.warning)
    },
  })
);
```

Which now makes me think, does Material-UI have some native helper that already does this?

Answer (score 0):

I digged in the Material-UI source code for a while and here is what I found:

- You can see any potential helper methods related to Material-UI style [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/packages/material-ui/src/styles).
- There is [this commit](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/commit/fad48de8f7d9a449adb4ab9796e9ed1c2c0593ca) that changed `palette.type` to `palette.mode`, if you Ctrl+F to search for `'light' ?` or `'dark' ?`, you'll see that they also use ternary operator to assign the colors based on the `dark` | `light` mode so I doubt they have any helper method like what you described in the second snippet.